# Why does the .NET Object Allocation Tool always says "No Allocation Occurred in the selected Timespan"?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I've been trying to figure out some of the memory issues I am having in an application.  I was trying to use the [.NET Object Allocation Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/dotnet-alloc-tool?view=vs-2022) to do so.

After letting it run through a scenario (a rather heavy one), the tool eventually loads, but only shows the following:

[image: object allocation tool]

I would imagine I should have **loads** of allocations, but according to the tool, there are none, no matter what timespan I span across.  Do I have to do something to enable this or am I missing something else??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tick the "Start with collection paused" option ?
If so, you need to actually click the "Record" button top left for it to start grabbing the details.
[image]

Comment: I think you're right.  I assumed that because the tool was running that it would be grabbing things automatically after you stopped, but I did not realize I needed to press record first.